# Focus on textarea based from anchor link

Tags: focus, textarea, anchor

I have a messaging function in my site that when a user clicks on a reply button they get redirected to the message and have the textarea focus based from the anchor link.

so the link structure is like this:

```
view_message/4fad37da1df#reply
```

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you need? What have you tried?

Comment: you have a bunch of messages, the #reply is an anchor link, when a user clicks on that, he will be linked to the message with the textarea already in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  $(window.location.hash).attr("tabindex", -1).focus();
}
```

It should check if the url has a hash in it, and if it does, give the target the tabindex attribute with a value of -1 and apply focus.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188217/430191 for the reason for the tabindex attribute (a related issue about keyboard focus in IE/Chrome/Safari)