# Firefox - hiding focus highlight when not on an input control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

We have a requirement whereby a page can consist of a form with several sections. Sections can be added or removed. After the user chooses to add a section the form is submitted and a new page returned with the new section added. The browser should scroll to the top of the new section. This is fine and I have  a generic jquery "scroll to anchor" solution working. However, in addition to simply setting `window.location()`, I also need to ensure that for keyboard users, hitting tab will take them to the next field after the anchor point. I'm using the solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593111/focus-on-textarea-based-from-anchor-link) to do this.

This works fine in IE 8/9 but in firefox(15), I'm seeing a little focus square being rendered where the anchor tag is. I would like to suppress this, I tried setting `display:none` but of course this stops the scroll working. I tried to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7egKz/1/) but jsFiddle doesn't demonstrate the problem as the fddle site itself is interfering with the focus setting - but the same code in the same browser running locally does.

here's a reduced version of my code that demonstrates the problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>test scroll</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form>
            <div>Blah</div>
            <div>
            <label for="a">Section 1: <input id="a" type="text" /></label>
        </div>
        <a id="scrollToAnchorSection2"></a>
        <div>
            <label for="b">Section 2: <input id="b" type="text" /></label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     /* Find any "scroll to anchors" that have been set */
    var anchors = $('[id*=scrollToAnchor]:first');
    if (anchors.length == 1) {
        window.location = "#" + anchors.attr("id");

        // Set tab position
        anchors.attr("tabindex", -1).focus();

    }
});
```

and css

```
div {
    margin-left:5em;
}
```

Comment: `$('input').blur(function (){...})`? isn't this what you need?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, wouldn't `a { outline: 0; }` take care of this?

Comment: @Val, wow yes! that worked. If you'd like to write that up as a proper answer I can give you the rep for providing the answer. I hadn;t appreciated the full possibilities of `blur`. This is an interesting comment form the jquery documentation. "The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as <input>. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types."

Comment: @SteveAtkinson obvisouly, assign classes, to them, dont' leave it as `$('input');` as this could affect every single input, and it may not be a wise idea, so it's better to use classes that way you may target only those inputs. which have that class so something like this `$('input.blurEffect').blur(...)`

Comment: @Val, thankls for that clarification but here it's fine. In this case, referring to my code above I simply add `anchors.blur()` as in this particular case, anchors will only contain the one element I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested...

the Blur function takes care of the input lost focus.

`$('input').blur(function (){...})?` isn't this what you need?

The jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) has this interesting comment.

*"The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as . In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types."*