# Accessibility, skip navigation doesn't work

Tags: html, cross-browser, accessibility

I built this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/CTTz3/)** to let you understand better what I mean.

Basically, I want to skip the navigation using just the keyboard and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> on the "**skip navigation**" link that have an anchor to the contents.

So, if you try to press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on **Skip navigation** and then <kbd>TAB</kbd> again you should focus the contents and not the links.

It works fine on FireFox, but it doesn't work on IE and Chrome.

There is a fix / way to do that?

Comment: See also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572843/skip-navigation-link-not-working-in-google-chrome)

Comment: yes it's interesting but for the moment I'd like to avoid js, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore Chrome, it has a bug, that I don't know the status of. The only way to do  it that comes to mind is using JavaScript, which I am not in favor of. Remove `tabindex=0` from the links in the `<ul>`.

Change `<div id="main">` to either `<div id="main" tabindex="-1">` or

```
<a id="main" name="main" tabindex="-1">
<div id="mainContent">...
```